# Custom Policy - Localized Claim within REST Technical Profile

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I need to pass an input claim with a localized `DefaultValue` within a **RESTful provider** technical profile (not within a Self-Asserted technical profile) of a custom policy but as soon as I add the reference to the transformation method `GetLocalizedStringsTransformation` within `InputClaimsTransformations` my application crashes.

The localized input claim **must** be within the **RESTful provider** technical profile.

**Custom Claim definition**:

```
<ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimType Id="localizedResult">
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
    </ClaimType>
</ClaimsSchema>
```

**Localization**:

```
<Localization Enabled="true">
    <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en" MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll">
      <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
      <SupportedLanguage>es</SupportedLanguage>
    </SupportedLanguages>
    <LocalizedResources Id="api.selfasserted.en">
      <LocalizedStrings>
        <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="localized_string">English Value</LocalizedString>
      </LocalizedStrings>
    </LocalizedResources>
    <LocalizedResources Id="api.selfasserted.es">
      <LocalizedStrings>
        <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="localized_string">Valor en Espanol</LocalizedString>
      </LocalizedStrings>
    </LocalizedResources>
</Localization>
```

**Claim Transformation**:

```
<ClaimsTransformations>
    <ClaimsTransformation Id="GetLocalizedStringsForCustomClaim" TransformationMethod="GetLocalizedStringsTransformation">
        <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="localizedResult" TransformationClaimType="localized_string" />
        </OutputClaims>
    </ClaimsTransformation>
</ClaimsTransformations>
```

**RESTful provider** technical profile:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="REST-Technical-Profile">
    <DisplayName>My App</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://my-app.test/api/endpoint</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetLocalizedStringsForCustomClaim" />
    </InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myCustomClaim" DefaultValue="{Claim:localizedResult}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
    </InputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

I tried with the method `CreateStringClaim` and it created a transformed value as expected but that method doesn't allow me to map translations based on language and custom translation collection.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the metadata setting to enable claim resolvers.
Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#using-claim-resolvers.

```xml
<Metadata>
    <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
</Metadata>
```

According to docs you need both this setting and using AlwaysUseDefaultValue=true for RESTful profiles.

Comment: Thank you @juunas but unfortunately it still does not work. Still getting `ADB2C: An exception has occurred`.

Comment: Can you add Application Insights logging and check from there what precisely goes wrong?

Comment: Thanks @juunas. I have. This is the error info in the Application Insights `"Message": "Execution of ClaimsTransformationImpl of Type \"Microsoft.Cpim.Data.Transformations.GetLocalizedStringsTransformation\" for TransformationMethod \"GetLocalizedStringsTransformation\" of ClaimsTransformation with id \"GetLocalizedStringsForCustomClaim\" in policy \"B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase\" of tenant \"mytenant.onmicrosoft.com\" threw an exception with the following message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."` However, I can't figure out what's the problem from that statement.

Comment: Hi @juunas, any hint on the above? Thank you

Comment: Well, it seems to be related to the claims transformation. But I don't see anything obviously wrong with it.